# Java only populating last if statement

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, jtable, filereader

I'm creating a patient tracking system for class. I need to read every line array in a text file and then find the date of the appointment. From there I will compare to today's date and if it returns 1 (so equal to today or in the future) then it will populate the future jtable. If it returns -1 it will need to populate the previous appointments table. It is currently reading every date, but I can only get it to populate one table with one previous date. I've tried a switch case and if statements and I can't seem to figure it out. Any suggestions are welcome.

```
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("appointments.txt"));
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("appointments.txt"));
        String line = "";
        
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            String in = s.nextLine();
            String[] sArray = in.split(",");
            String day = sArray[7].toString();
            SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
            Date date = parser.parse(day);
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
            String formattedDate = formatter.format(date);

            Date todayDate = new Date();

            Object[][] data = {};
            String[] columnNames = {"Date/Time", "Doctor", "Location", "PreAppointment", "Cancel/Reschedule"};
            dm2 = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
            table2 = new JTable(dm2);
            
            Object[][] data2 = {};
            String[] columnNames1 = {"Date/Time", "Doctor", "Location", "View Details"};
            dm = new DefaultTableModel(data2, columnNames1);
            table = new JTable(dm);
            for (String word : sArray) {
                if (word.equals(userInput)) {

                    
                    System.out.println(formattedDate);

                    int result = date.compareTo(todayDate);
                    System.out.println("result: " + result);

                    if (result == 0) {
                        dm2.addRow(new Object[]{formattedDate + " " + sArray[8].toString(),
                            sArray[4].toString(),
                            sArray[6].toString() + " " + sArray[12].toString(),
                            "PreAppointment",
                            "Cancel/Reschedule"});
                        

                    } else if (result > 0) {
                        dm2.addRow(new Object[]{formattedDate + " " + sArray[8].toString(),
                            sArray[4].toString(),
                            sArray[6].toString() + " " + sArray[12].toString(),
                            "PreAppointment",
                            "Cancel/Reschedule"});

                    } else if (result < 0) {
                        dm.addRow(new Object[]{formattedDate + " " + sArray[8].toString(),
                            sArray[4].toString(),
                            sArray[6].toString() + " / " + sArray[12].toString(),
                            "Details"});

                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: What value does `userInput` hold? Could it be, that `word.equals(userInput)` is true only once?

Comment: Can you `System.out.println(date);` before loop to see if `day` is correctly formatted  into `date` ?

Comment: Why are you creating new `JTable`s and new `DefaultTableModel`s for each line that you read?

Comment: @Thomas Kläger Thank you! I actually didn't even realize that it was inside the while loop! I moved it out of it and it works now! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you creating new `JTable`s and new `DefaultTableModel`s for each line that you read?

Excerpt from your code:

```
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

        // [...]

        Object[][] data = {};
        String[] columnNames = {"Date/Time", "Doctor", "Location", "PreAppointment", "Cancel/Reschedule"};
        dm2 = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        table2 = new JTable(dm2);
        
        Object[][] data2 = {};
        String[] columnNames1 = {"Date/Time", "Doctor", "Location", "View Details"};
        dm = new DefaultTableModel(data2, columnNames1);
        table = new JTable(dm);

        // [...]

    }
```

That should be:

```
    Object[][] data = {};
    String[] columnNames = {"Date/Time", "Doctor", "Location", "PreAppointment", "Cancel/Reschedule"};
    dm2 = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
    table2 = new JTable(dm2);
        
    Object[][] data2 = {};
    String[] columnNames1 = {"Date/Time", "Doctor", "Location", "View Details"};
    dm = new DefaultTableModel(data2, columnNames1);
    table = new JTable(dm);

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        // [...]
    }
```